# Accessing Unicode telugu text from Ms-Access Database in Java

Tags: java, ms-access, unicode, jdbc

I have an MS-Access database ( A English-telugu Dictionary database) which contains a table storing English words and telugu meanings.

I am writing a dictionary program in Java which queries the database for a keyword entered by the user and display the telugu meaning.

My Program is working fine till I get the data from the database, but when I displayed it on some component like JTextArea/JEditorPane/ etc... the telugu text is being displayed as '????'. Why is it happening?.

I have seen the solution for "1467412/reading-unicode-data-from-an-access-database-using-jdbc" which provides some workaround for Hebrew language. But it is not working for telugu. i.e I included setCharset("UTF8")before querying from the database. but still I am getting all '?'s.

As soon as I got data from Resultset I am checking the individual characters, all the telugu characters are being encoded by 63 only. This is my observation. I guess this must be some type of encoding problem. I would be very glad if somebody provides some solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to display Teleugu characters at all, for example by invoking setText("\0c05 \0c06 \0c07") on your text component?

Comment: Yes. I only have problem with the content received from the database.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the text from the database, before you display in Java Swing widgets, are you setting the font? Set the font to "Gautami" and see whether it solves the problem;